# Java alternative of "Google code prettifier"

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, syntax, pretty-print

I would like to do exactly what "google code prettifier" (syntax highlighting of code snippets in a web page) does, but on serverside using java.

Comment: why do you want to make your server prettify code instead that let the browser of every visitor do it? You would save a lot of work..

Comment: @Jack, +1. Plus, if you change settings in the Code Formatter, if it's client-based, the changes will occur in every post, while if it's server-based and performed once, all the old records will be left untouched. By the way, try this one: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: I want to do on server side because I want to avoid the client side blink right after the javascript parses the code. This "Blink" occurs specially when the parsed code is very long.

Comment: If you want to avoid the blink.. render it to a hidden div, then format, then display the div

Comment: There are other ways to avoid that. For instance, don't display the unformatted text; display the text only after formatting. This can still be incremental, btw, users won't be able to tell a slow parse apart from a slow load.

Comment: MSalters you are right. The same idea was coming to my mind, just after replying to Alex and Jack... Thank you folks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I have used [Java2HTML](http://www.java2html.com/) to convert source code to HTML.

Comment: After a small research I found out that there are two java2Html with the same name. The other one is http://java2html.de which seems to be a better alternative for me. Unfortunately both are released using GPL. And my boss would preffer an LGPL library ... :(

Comment: I have also downloaded Java2html , and I have eclipse installed. Can you guide how did you run Java2HTML  ? (I want to integrate it to my own java program).